# Info about items and signal in QTreeView - PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtreeview

There are rows in QTreeView, each row has two columns.
The first column carries a name, second column carries a preview.

Questions:

1. How to get click on row signal? If row is selected by single mouse click, how to get signal? I use `QTreeView.doubleClicked.connect()` now, but is there way how to do?
2. I follow up on the first question. If I choose by clicking on the item in the second column how to get item name from the first column? (if is not possible to perform the action with a single mouse click, how to do it with `QTreeView.doubleClicked.connect()`? )
3. How to get information about category, subcategories, row, column of item?

Thanks for hints and help.

Code preview:

1. QTreeView

```
self.tree = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self.tree)
self.tree.setDragEnabled(True)
self.tree.doubleClicked.connect(self.getValue)
```

2. Filling QTreeView

```
self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(('Category / Subcategories / Name', 'Preview'))
self.tree.setModel(self.model)
self.tree.setColumnWidth(0, 200)
#root = self.tree.rootIndex()
for row, (keys, vals) in enumerate(self.dataStatObj.items()):
    if row == 0:
        kategorie = keys[0]
        podkategorie = keys[1]
        categoryTV = QtGui.QStandardItem(keys[0])
        subcategoriesTV = QtGui.QStandardItem(keys[1])
        self.model.appendRow(categoryTV)
        for iimg in listImagesNameSuffix:
            if iimg[1] == keys[2]:
                print(iimg[1])
                print(keys[2])
                imgName = iimg[0]
        imgTV = StandardItemObr()
        imgTV.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(pathToImages + imgName))
        imgTV.setEditable(False)
        nameImgTV = QStandardItem(keys[2])
        nameImgTV.setEditable(False)
        categoryTV.appendRow(subcategoriesTV)
        categoryTV.setEditable(False)
        subcategoriesTV.appendRow([nameImgTV, imgTV])
        subcategoriesTV.setEditable(False)
    ...
    ...
        
self.tree.expandAll()
self.tree.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
```

3. getValue (`self.tree.doubleClicked.connect(self.getValue)`)

```
def getValue(self, val):
    print(val.data(), 'If I click on the first column, the text will appear.'
                      ' When I click on the second column I need to return the same as for the first column ')
    if val.data() is None:
        print('None')
        print(val.parent(), "PARENT")
```

4. Preview

[image: Click on second column (there is QIcon)]

Comment: What do you mean by "is there way how to do it?"? Also, you are talking about *clicking*, but you're using the doubleclick signal, and you want to get a row, but a tree model has different level of "rows", depending on the parent item. Please try to clarify what you want to know, as right now your questions are a bit confusing.

Comment: @musicamante instead of double-clicking, I would like to get information by simply selecting the row where the preview (image QIcon) is located. And I need get name (text) in example - House_01. And I want to get information about what category and subcategory holds this row. Thanks

Comment: @musicamante I've edited the question, I hope it's understandable now

Comment: You need to use the [selection-model](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel) of the tree-view to track selection changes. Use the [selectionChanged signal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectionChanged) to do this, so that you get notifications from both mouse and keyboard interaction.

Comment: @Pr.Syn you're welcome; please consider the last suggestion in my answer, it is very important to carefully research and study the documentation, especially for a toolkit as huge and complex as Qt is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QTreeView, like other views such as QListView or QTableView, inherits from [QAbstractItemView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html), and if you look at the [Signals section](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#signals) you'll see that there are other signals other than `doubleClicked`. What you need, obviously, is the [`clicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#clicked) signal.

That signal, like most of the others, returns the *model index*
(a [QModelIndex](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html) instance) that has been clicked, which is an object that is used to locate the data within the model, including its "coordinates": row, column and *parent* (the last is fundamental for tree models).

The QModelIndex class has various convenience functions that allow easy access to the relation with the model:

- [`data()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#data), which you're already using, that returns the value(s) associated to that specific index in the model; it's actually a "shortcut" to `model.data(index, role)`;
- [`parent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#parent) is pretty explanatory; same as `model.parent(index)`;
- [`sibling()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#sibling), returns an index at the specified row or column that shares the same *parent* of the given one; it's the same as `model.sibling(row, column, index)`;

Considering the above, if you want to get data about the first column after a click, you need to connect the function to the `clicked` signal; then, in order to get information about any possible parent, you can use a basic recursive function:

```
def getValue(self, index):
    if index.column():
        index = index.sibling(index.row(), 0)
        # since Qt 5.11 you can use `index.siblingAtColumn(0)`

    def getValueRecursive(index):
        info = ['"{}" (row {}, col {})'.format(
            index.data(), index.row(), index.column())]
        if index.parent().isValid():
            info.extend(getValueRecursive(index.parent()))
        return info

    print('Index clicked!')
    for indexInfo in reversed(getValueRecursive(index)):
        print(indexInfo)
```

Note that the `clicked` signal will obviously only work for *mouse clicks*: if the current index is changed using the keyboard, it will not be emitted, so you should better use the [`selectionModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel) of the view and use the [`selectionChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectionChanged) or [`currentChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#currentChanged) signals instead.

<sup>I strongly recommend you to carefully and patiently study the classes you're using, including the inherited ones; for instance, if you're using QTreeView, you should consider studying all the documentation about: [QAbstractItemView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html), [QAbstractScrollArea](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html), [QFrame](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qframe.html), [QWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) and, finally, [QObject](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html); since you're using models, you also need to know more about [QModelIndex](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html), [QAbstractItemModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html) and read the documentation about the [model/view framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html).</sup>